# Oracle Apex Default "Create"-Button

Tags: oracle-apex

I realised when creating a form with Apex (Version 19.2)  a "create" button is generated. This one's behaviour is set to "define by dynamic option". Now the issue and the question at the same time is the fact that upon changing the behaviour once and then returning it back to the default setting the button will stop working.
If I were to create a new button I would have to manualy write all the insert operations for the whole form which I want to avoid.
Is this a bug from Apex itself or am I missing something?

Comment: Create a form in another page on the same table and compare the settings. You should be able to recreate it like it was before, there is no magic...

Comment: Even though the question sounds stupid, i tried doing that before asking. Also I tried  to copy the button from another page. The result was the same, the button was simply not working,

Comment: I know the feeling - it takes a bit of getting used to. I would recreate the form on another page and copy over the additional functionality you have written. Alternatively if you can create an example on apex.oracle.com I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: I fiured it out. The issue was that the branch point was set to "Processing" and this option was to slow for a bigger form. While the form itself was smaller it was working while the option is not suited for bigger forms. Switching the Point to " After Processing" did the trick.

Comment: For me I had to recreate the button

Answer (score 0):

I've found that in Oracle Apex (I'm working in v20.2), sometimes it's just easier to recreate something than to spend hours hunting for the reason it doesn't work. I copy the code I need to my NotePad and then copy the code to the new something. As it was in this particular example I spent 2 hours searching for the problem, whilst actually fixing the problem (with a new button) only took 5 minutes. Part of my problem was that I didn't know why the button wasn't clicking (no pun intended).

In this particular case it was a button on a form that calls "Form - Automatic Row Processing (DML)", using a Create button that calls "SQL INSERT action" Database Action. The problem happened when I changed the form from Modal to Non Modal and Back again.